# Unittesting problem with session starting/closing

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am having an problem writing unit tests for an simple session wrapper.

The class itself has some basic functions `set`, `get`, `exists` etc.
All these functions have an check `assertSessionStart` which does the following:

```
protected static function assertStarted()
{
    if (strlen(session_id()) < 1) {
        throw new Exception("Some text here");
    }
    return;
}
```

When writing my unit sets, I have the following `setUp` and `tearDown` methods. I have these because I want every test that runs to have a fresh session environment.

```
protected function setUp() {
    session_start();
}
protected function tearDown() {
    session_destroy();
}
```

Now to the problem, I want an test method which fails when I attempt to use `set` when I don't have an session started. In order to do this, I will have to destroy the session started in `setUp`. Like this:

```
public function testGetWithoutSession() {
        session_destroy();
        $this->setExpectedException('Exception');
        ESL_Session::set('set', 'value');
        session_start();
    }
```

This however throws an warning 'Trying to destroy uninitialized session'. When I put an `echo session_id()` right in front of `session_destroy` though - it shows me that I have an valid session.

Does anyone have experience unit testing session wrappers?

**Additional information**:

1. PHP Version 5.3.6
2. Linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens because at this point:

```
    session_destroy();
    $this->setExpectedException('Exception');
    ESL_Session::set('set', 'value'); // HERE <----
    session_start(); // This is not called anymore!
```

there is an exception and `session_start();` isn't called anymore.

My suggestion would be to change to change your `tearDown` to only call `session_destory` when there is an active session. So in the `tearDown` **"Only clean up if you have to"**.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, had me going blind.

Comment: Or you can catch the exception instead of using `setExpectedException()`. Add `self::fail()` inside the try block after the call to `set()`.

Comment: That is interesting, I'm pretty new to PHPUnit (and unit testing in general). Thanks for the comment!

Comment: In this case, however, I would go with edorian's solution as it's more general. By having `tearDown()` check that the session has been started before destroying it, you'll be prepared for an unexpected exception from any test.

Comment: While we're at it. You can also use the @expectedException annotation, thats usually the preferred way of telling phpunit that an exception should be thrown. But all 3 approaches are valid :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have your nice session class wrapper I discourage to use everytime `session_id();` for your assert.

Just put a propierty

```
private $started = false;
```

and then in your

```
protected function setUp() {
    session_start();
    $this->started=true;
}
```

So you can do your `assertStarted()` based on $started

Comment: The assert is within class I am unit-testing. `Session`. The `setUp` is part of the `SessionTest` class. It needs to be reset, because every tests must meet the same condition.

Comment: you don't have setUp in your original Session class?

Comment: No, `setUp` is an function used by PHPUnit and is run before each individual Test function. As `tearDown` is run after every Test. They have nothing to do with the tested Class.

Comment: so in your production script who calls session_start?

Comment: That doesn't matter - as the wrapper can be used in any environment. The wrapper itself just demands that there is an session started, it doesn't start itself.